# Can we deduce selfish behaviour from altruism?

Tags: ethics, evolution

In (biological) evolutionary theory, there are various theories about how altruism evolved via the 'selfish' behaviour of genes.

There are analogical ideas on the economic & ethical spheres. Where altruism is derived as a consequence of selfish drives (Hobbes).

Are there philosophers who've tried an opposite tack, where selfish behaviour has been derived from altruism?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to your inquiry but more a direction where I would look: beliefs in all manner of [golden ages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_age), when everything and everyone were better than later. If someone had maintained that belief, they might have come up with the mechanism of how selfishness could have arisen in a community of ideal human beings - e.g. through [corruption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_man) by some evil forces.

Maybe you could look among philosophers that idealize man's ["state of nature"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_nature) as opposed to the alleged corruption through civilization. (Not that I've found anyone on linked wikipedia pages, it's just the hypothesis of where such sentiment could have arisen).

Comment: "philosophers that idealize man's "state of nature" as opposed to the alleged corruption through civilization": That would be Rousseau, for example. I think you can find more about that in the *Discourse on Inequality* than in the *Social Contract*.

Answer (score 1):

"I am more altruistic than you, so that which benefits me should go to me instead of you; if I let you have it, that would be less altruistic."

<sup>I'm not aware of anyone having done this, but probably only because it's not very interesting.  It's *really* easy to get selfishness.</sup>

Comment: I think it were airplane safety experts: "If traveling with children, or the elderly, put on your [oxigen] mask first, then help with theirs" (i.e. be selfish so you can be altruistic)

Comment: @artm - That was going to be my point #2 if I needed another.

Comment: I'm really talking at a more fundamental level than this. Political theorists are using selfish behaviour to understand/model/govern all human polities; evolutionists using 'selfish genes' to model all biological life. I'm not talking about small-scale behaviour.

Comment: I'm reading Platos republic at the moment, and I think he might have something to say about it. But its going to take a couple of rereadings.

Comment: @Kerr:I don't follow your argument, it doesn't make sense, or is at best sophistry; at least artm does.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - If you altruistically give to someone who will be altruistic in turn, will there be more or less altruism overall than if you give to someone who will be selfish?  Okay, now generalize (assuming that you are reasonably altruistic).  (artm's addition: if you are needy, and soak up altruistic acts yourself, will there be more or less altruism than if you are greedy and take care of yourself, at least?)

Comment: @Kerr: I don't think you apply quantitative methods to ethical acts.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - All consequentialist approaches have a quantitative aspect (as do most evolutionary arguments).  I'm not sure what you mean to rule out or critique here.

Comment: @Kerr: Are you talking about sociobiology? I don't see why consequentialist approach must have a quantifiable aspect; the only one I know of is Utilitarianism, which I tend to dismiss, simply because I do not *understand* what it means to add one good act to another; whether a bad act cancels out a good one; whether an ordering of goodness can be made, globally or even locally.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - Evolution deals in _fitness_, which is inherently mathematical.  Consequentialism requires you to consider the _consequences_ of your actions, compare them, and pick the best (comparison is inherently a mathematical operation).  The fundamental premise behind consequentialism is that _all states of affair are comparable_--there is some basis upon which to rank them.  If you reject that, you must also reject consequentialism of every sort or accept undecidable moral choices (though you may follow e.g. rules-based utilitarianism without understanding why the rules were chosen).